# Recursive function doesn't return correct value

Tags: visual-c++, recursion

I have a recursive function. It does recursive search of folder which name is given in second argument inside drive or folder which name given in first argument. The folder given in second argument can locate on any path and any nesting level inside drive or folder given in first argument.
So function browse all content of drive or folder specified in first argument for finding of folder specified in second argument. Below is function itself:

```
wstring FolderPathValidator::FindRequiredFolder(const wstring& p_InitialPath, wstring p_RequiredFolderName)
{
      wstring foundFolder = L"";
      wstring folderPath = p_InitialPath + L"\\*";
      WIN32_FIND_DATAW folderInfo;
      HANDLE search_handle = FindFirstFileW(folderPath.c_str(), &folderInfo);
      if (search_handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
      {
           vector<wstring> folders;

           do
           {
                if (folderInfo.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
                {
                     if ((!lstrcmpW(folderInfo.cFileName, L".")) || (!lstrcmpW(folderInfo.cFileName, L"..")))
                     continue;
                }

                folderPath = p_InitialPath + L"\\" + wstring(folderInfo.cFileName);

                if (folderInfo.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
                {
                     if (folderInfo.cFileName == p_RequiredFolderName)
                     {
                          foundFolder = folderInfo.cFileName;
                          return foundFolder;
                     }
                     folders.push_back(folderPath);
                }
           } while (FindNextFileW(search_handle, &folderInfo));

           ::FindClose(search_handle);

           for (vector<wstring>::iterator iter = folders.begin(), end = folders.end(); iter != end; ++iter)
               FindRequiredFolder(*iter, p_RequiredFolderName);
      }

      return foundFolder;
}
```

And in code I call it in the following manner:

```
wstring FoundFolder = FindRequiredFolder(L"C:", L"TextFiles_to_Test");
```

But if I direct my function to knowingly right way (where the folder given in second argument exists) it return an empty string. How should I correct the code so the function returns folder found.

I add that I check in debugger step by step and there I see that the function finds required folder but returns an empty string in its call operator.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
wstring FoundFolder = FindRequiredFolder(L"C:\\", L"TextFiles_to_Test");
```

You are starting your search in whatever the *current working directory* for the "C:" drive is - not the *root* directory of the C: drive.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not returning the right thing when you get to the required folder name -

```
if (folderInfo.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
{
        if (folderInfo.cFileName == p_RequiredFolderName)
        {
            return folderPath;  // <-- return the found (fully qualified) path name
        }
        // else
        folders.push_back(folderPath);
}
```

You might have a few problems with this approach, though (you may have already considered these):
First, this will return the first match, regardless of where it appears in the tree. Consider:

```
    c:\a\system
    c:\windows\system
    c:\tmp\system
```

This might be an issue for you.
Also, it takes a fair bit of time.  I looked for `foo1219`, which I just created in `c:\tmp` and it took a while (recycle bin, documents, program files, etc., are all costly).  If you have any user interface for this, you might want to use a dialog box and let the user select a folder.  The common dialogs File dialog box could be very helpful.

Comment: I thnk about dialog box but in requirements specification from customer says that user will input folder name from command line.

Comment: What must I return before the brace that close the body of the function folder name or fully qualified path name to the folder?

Comment: It didn't help. In case of returned path the function returns currently checked path. But it is wrong. The function must return either required folder path or an empty string if the folder doesn't exists.

Comment: If I do this:  
    
    int main()
    {
        std::wstring str = FindRequiredFolder(L"C:\\", L"todolist");
        wprintf(L"%s\n", str.c_str());
        return 0;
    }


I get this:  
    C:\tmp>so-findpath  
    C:\\bin\todolist

Please clarify what you are expecting.

Comment: I need in the following. If required folder was found, the function must return fully qualified path to this folder. If required folder wasn't find, the function must return an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the fully qualified path to the first folder that matches `p_RequiredFolderName`.  If `p_RequiredFolderName` does not exist, an empty string is returned:

```
wstring FindRequiredFolder(const wstring& p_InitialPath, const wstring& p_RequiredFolderName)
{
    wstring foundFolder;
    wstring searchSpec = p_InitialPath + L"\\*";
    WIN32_FIND_DATAW folderInfo;
    HANDLE search_handle = ::FindFirstFileW(searchSpec.c_str(), &folderInfo);
    if (search_handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        do{
            if (folderInfo.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY){
                if ((!lstrcmpW(folderInfo.cFileName, L".")) || (!lstrcmpW(folderInfo.cFileName, L"..")))
                    continue;

                wstring fullPath = p_InitialPath + L"\\" + folderInfo.cFileName;
                if (folderInfo.cFileName == p_RequiredFolderName){
                    foundFolder = fullPath;  // we're done.
                }
                else{
                    foundFolder = FindRequiredFolder(fullPath, p_RequiredFolderName);
                }
                if (foundFolder.length()){
                    break;
                }
            }
        } while (::FindNextFileW(search_handle, &folderInfo));

        ::FindClose(search_handle);
    }
    return foundFolder;
}
```

Comment: @user3769902: happy to help.  if this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27568785/recursive-function-doesnt-return-correct-value/27573447#27573447 is the answer you pinged me about, is it accepted?  This might also be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27568785/recursive-function-doesnt-return-correct-value/27584344#27584344.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about that caveat I mentioned earlier about returning the *first matching folder*, so I threw this together:

```
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

// Find *all* folders in a directory tree with a given name.
// Params:
//    initialPath      location to start search
//    searchForName    name of folder to search for
//    locations        vector in which to put paths for any matches
//  Returns
//    vector containing all matches (if any).  Same as input parameter,
//    helps with performance on recursion (and also RVO).
std::vector<std::wstring> 
FindRequiredFolderLocations(const std::wstring& initialPath, 
                            const std::wstring& searchForName,
                            std::vector<std::wstring>& locations
                           )
{
    std::wstring searchSpec = initialPath + L"\\*";

    WIN32_FIND_DATA folderInfo;
    HANDLE search_handle = ::FindFirstFile(searchSpec.c_str(), &folderInfo);
    if (search_handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        do{
            if (folderInfo.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY){
                if ((!lstrcmp(folderInfo.cFileName, L".")) || (!lstrcmp(folderInfo.cFileName, L"..")))
                    continue;

                std::wstring fullPath = initialPath + L"\\" + folderInfo.cFileName;
                if (folderInfo.cFileName == searchForName){
                    locations.push_back(fullPath);
                }
                FindRequiredFolderLocations(fullPath, searchForName, locations);
            }
        } while (::FindNextFile(search_handle, &folderInfo));

        ::FindClose(search_handle);
    }
    return locations;
}

// Overload not requiring "locations" vector parameter (see above)
std::vector<std::wstring> 
FindRequiredFolderLocations(const std::wstring& initialPath, 
                            const std::wstring& folderName)
{
    std::vector<std::wstring> result;
    return FindRequiredFolderLocations(initialPath, folderName, result);
}

#ifdef TEST_FRFL
#include <iostream>
void FRFL_Test(const std::wstring& folderName)
{
    std::vector<std::wstring> locations;

    FindRequiredFolderLocations(L"C:",  folderName, locations);
    size_t count = locations.size();
    if (0 == count){
        std::wcout << L"Required folder not found.\n";
    }
    else if (1 == count){
        std::wcout << L"One location found: " << locations[0] << L"\n";
    }
    else{
        std::wcout << L"multiple locations found for required folder name:\n";
        for (auto loc : locations){
            std::wcout << L"\t" << loc.c_str() << L"\n";
        }
        std::wcout << L"Which one do you want?\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    FRFL_Test(L"!!exists_1_Location");
    FRFL_Test(L"!!exists_several_Locations");
    FRFL_Test(L"!!exists_nowhere");

    return 0;
}

#endif
```

Build:

```
C:\tmp>cl /nologo /EHsc /W4 /DTEST_FRFL so-findpathw.cpp
```

Ran the following commands to create test directories:

```
C:\tmp>md frfl
C:\tmp>md frfl\a
C:\tmp>md frfl\a\b
C:\tmp>md frfl\a\b\!!exists_1_Location
C:\tmp>md frfl\a\!!exists_several_Locations
C:\tmp>md frfl\a\b\!!exists_several_Locations
C:\tmp>md frfl\!!exists_several_Locations
C:\tmp>md !!exists_several_Locations
```

Output:

```
C:\tmp>so-findpathw
One location found: C:\tmp\frfl\a\b\!!exists_1_Location
multiple locations found for required folder name:
      C:\tmp\!!exists_several_Locations
      C:\tmp\frfl\!!exists_several_Locations
      C:\tmp\frfl\a\!!exists_several_Locations
      C:\tmp\frfl\a\b\!!exists_several_Locations
Which one do you want?
Required folder not found.
```

Don't know if you'll need this, but finding any folder that matches the directory basename you are looking for *regardless of where it is actually located in the tree* just really bothered me.  I'm a bit obsessive like that.